# OWL Carousel no function

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

I want to use OWL Carousel. I have dreated a test.php

Where are the mistakes?

```
<script>

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})

</script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

I have add the stylesheet links and jquery and the .js directly from the source page!
This test.php not work! Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?

Without any context, I would say you need to make sure the document is in a ready state before you try to access it with jQuery. Since your script section comes before your html, your javascript will execute before the ".owl-carousel" exists. You can achieve ready state by wrapping your code with the following event handler, or moving your script section after your html.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // your code goes here
});
```